# iOS8 Xcode6 UICollectionView sizeForIndexPath: does not get called on rotation

Tags: objective-c, uicollectionview, ios8, xcode6, uicollectionviewcell

My project has a UICollectionView with a custom cell that used to work perfectly on iPhone and iPad before iOS8. Now in iPad on first load cells look perfect but on rotation

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

does not get called.

Problem is this is where my rotation logic goes and that's why my UICollectionView twitches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what solved it:
I added the bottom line to my didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation: method

```
-(void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation{
[super didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:fromInterfaceOrientation];
[self.collectionView performBatchUpdates:nil completion:nil];
```

}

Comment: I'm seeing the same thing.  The problem is that didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation happens after the rotation animations take place, and the result is pretty ugly.  I tried this hack in viewWillLayoutSubviews, but it didn't work.  Anyone found a solution during rotation?